# htaccess login form IE issues

Tags: php, .htaccess, internet-explorer, authentication, .htpasswd

I've been using info from here on Stacked and have now got an HTML form for use with htaccess, the login info get sent via login.php

```
<form name=login method = post action = "/login.php">
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input name=username type=text value="user.name" size=20>
<br><br>
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input name=password type=password value="password" size=20>
<input type=submit name=Login value=Login>
</form>
```

Here is my login.php

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$link = "www.url.com/secure/";
$URL="http://$name:$password@$link";
header ("Location: $URL");
?>
```

The problem I have is that with IE it just goes to login.php and give me a 'page cannot be displayed' message.

I'm doing it this way as Safari and apple devices give you an annoying 'phishing' warning thus why I am sending to login.php

Any idea how i can get IE to handle this like every other browser, to just login to the secure directory.

Comment: Off topic, but you *really* need to URL-encode your POST variables before sticking them into your URL string like that, otherwise anyone with a `#` or an `@` in their password is going to fail, and it could be used by hackers to redirect to any arbitrary site they wanted.

Comment: yeh that's fine, i can sort that, just the main bit of sorting this is my big issue! :(